# Is it an example of bilinear pairing?

Tags: pairings

Consider a bilinear pairing $e: G_1 \times G_2 \rightarrow G_T$. Let's assume, $G_1 = G_2 = G_T = (\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$, i.e. additive group of integer modulo $n$ and $e(x,y) = xy$ mod $n$. Isn't it an example of bilinear map?

$G_1 = G_2 = G_T = (\mathbb{Z}_n,\ast)$, i.e. multiplicative group of integer modulo $n$ and $e(x,y) = y^x$ mod $n$, is it still a bilinear map?

Can there be other bilinear map defined over $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

**EDIT**:

---

Actually all my question were to understand [Groth-Sahai proof system](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/155). Here, they have recast the general equation to fit the form of a quadratic equation. (See teh highlighted part below). But, how can they remark that all maps with $f(x,y) = xy$ mod $n$ will satisfy properties of bilinear pairing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The second one is not bilinear: $e(x,y^z) =x^{(y^z)} \neq (x^{yz})} = e(x,y)^z$. For the first one I don't see the problem with bilinearity at the moment, but the group is pretty useless for crypto since discrete log is trivial.

Comment: Exactly that's what I thought, I wanted to verify

Comment: To be useful in crypto, the bilinear function has to be nondegrading, and the dlog problem has to be hard in all three groups (well, if it is hard in the target group, the other two follow).

Comment: I have just edited my original question. Please have a look.

Comment: After the edit, still no hard problem in this group.

Comment: I am not trying to find a hrd problem instance. Here, they have recast the general equation to fit the form of a quadratic equation. (See the highlighted part above). But, how can they remark that all maps with $f(x,y) = xy$ mod $n$ will satisfy properties of bilinear pairing?

Answer (score 3):

Not only is $\mathbb G_1 = \mathbb G_2 = \mathbb G_T = \mathbb Z_p$ with $e(x,y) = x \cdot y \pmod{p}$ an example of a "bilinear group" (a triple of groups with a bilinear map) but *every* bilinear group of prime order is isomorphic to one of this form. So anything you want to know in principle about such groups, you can calculate on this example. I've used it myself before now as a sanity-check for some protocols.

The security of e.g. ECC implementations of bilinear groups rests on the fact that the isomorphisms to the $\mathbb Z_p$ form are not (thought to be) efficiently computable.

Of course it's cryptographically useless --- discrete logs are easy, as commenters have pointed out. But cryptographic definitions usually come in two parts, functionality and security. An encryption scheme for example is a triple (KeyGen, Enc, Dec) with a correctness property; the scheme where Enc and Dec are the identity maps is therefore an encryption scheme. Only when we introduce security requirements in a second step does this scheme turn out to be lacking. The same goes for $\mathbb Z_p$: it certainly is a "bilinear group" but not a particularly secure one.

EDIT: to answer your last question whether one can define other bilinear maps over $(\mathbb Z_p, +) \times (\mathbb Z_p, +)$: note that $1$ is a generator of $\mathbb Z_p$ so $e(x,y)$ is completely determined for all $x,y$ by $e(1,1)$. If you want a non-degenerate bilinear map, $e(1,1)$ has to be a generator of $\mathbb G_T = \mathbb Z_p$ too, and whichever generator you pick, the structures that you get are isomorphic. If you drop the non-degeneracy requirement, the map that sends everything to $0$ is a different, trivially bilinear one.

Answer (score 0):

Commonly, one uses multiplicative groups. When recall definition of a pairing, it must be bilinear, non degenerate, and easy to compute.
Note that the definition of e(x,y)=x.y can be interpreted as a external product. (x.y = y+...+y: n-times) and not as the internal group law.

I agree with Maeher's answer. The first example is a bilinear pairing, but not the second as it's not symmetric.
However the first example, can't be used for cryptographic protocol. Given:  x $\ne 0\cdots $, m.x, n.x, and s.x,  it would be easy to compute (mns).e(x,x).
As example we can build other bilinear pairings, by just considering all linear maps u, v and the pairing (x,y) -> u(x).u(y) which satisfy non degeneracy, the computability is obvious.
When using multiplicative structure, definition of pairing is still satisfied, but can't be used for cryptography, as BDHP is trivial.

**EDIT:** Consider final conclusion, (x,y)->x.y not a pairing. Any additional suggestion?

Comment: I didn't get the last remark, "When using multiplicative structure, definition of pairing is still satisfied..."

Comment: Sorry, I'm not english fluent. I just remarked that if we consider multiplicative groups such as $Z/n.Z$, then then (x,y) -> x.y is a pairing. But in this case BDHP is trivial.

Comment: According to you, $G_1 = G_2 = G_T = \mathbb{Z}_n^\times$. Also, $e(x,y)=x.y$, where the dot(.) operation represents MULTIPLICATION MODULO $n$. But, is it really a bilinear map? Say, $e(2.3,4) = e(6,4) = 2$ and again $e(2.3,4) = e(2,4).e(3,4) = 8.1 = 8$. Bilinearity fails.

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock: I think that there is a confusion. the definition of a pairing implies that $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on the group $G_T$.
Here the ring Z acts on $G_T$ by the following way:
$n.x = x* \cdots *x$ -ntimes. Then $n.x=x^n$ which is different from the definition of the inner multiplication law in $G_T$.
This is why in all the example, to avoid confusion, $e(n.P,m.Q)=e(P,Q)^{n.m}$ is generally prefered.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mess of the notation. Let's denote the inner multiplication as $\ast$ to avoid confusion. Consider, $n = 11$. But, if I want to replay my previous example: $e(2.3,4) = e(3 \ast 3,4) = e(9,4) = 3$. The other way round, $e(2.3,4) = e(3,4)^2 = 1^2 = 1 \ast 1 = 1$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock: No, your computation is correct. Unless I'm a little bit confusing about the value of e(3,4)=1. Some Pairing definition state that the value of a pairing is in the pth-root of Unity. If we consider G={1,3,4,5,9} as a sub-group of order 5 (prime) of $G_1, G_2, G_T$ then e is a pairing as 3, and 1 are all 5th-root of unity. This is what we know from the Weil and Tate Pairing.
Please check the general definition and confirm!

Comment: Complement: n=11: then $Z/nZ$ is cyclic and is of order 10. There are two distinct sub-groups of order 2 and 5. This is of great importance in EC, to build curves of maximal group order.

Comment: Even if $e$ is defined with respect to those groups of order $2$ and $5$, isn't it incorrect to remark that $e(x,y) = x \ast y$ is a bilinear map on $\mathbb{Z}_p^\ast$?

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock: I think you've find a good counterexample, and now that (x,y)->x.y couldn't be considered as a pairing.
following your remark and if my math is correct, if g is a generator of the cyclic group of prime order p.

If we let e be a pairing then we would have:
$\forall r, s \in \mathbb{Z} \; : e(g^r,g^s)=g^r.g^s=g^{r+s}=e(g,g)^{rs}=g^{2rs} $ which give : $$2rs \equiv r+s \; mod \; [p-1]\; \forall r, s \in \mathbb{Z}$$
which is absurd!